# syntax error on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm receiving this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '90'.

when i tried to compile this t-sql:

```
ALTER DATABASE SGCT SET compatibility_level = 90
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What is the SQL-Server Version u r working on ??

Comment: I am Working On SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL SERVER – 2005 try to use:

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel AdventureWorks, 80;
GO
```

[More details](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-2005-change-database-compatible-level-backward-compatibility/)

Answer (score 1):

Sets certain database behaviors to be compatible with the specified version of SQL Server. You are already using 2005 and 90 is to set for 2005. If you need to do a backward COMPATIBILITY

You should try this.

```
ALTER DATABASE SGCT 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80;
GO
```